# How to detect fragment is idle for some time in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, fragment-lifecycle

I want to check that no one has interacted with fragment UI for some time and on the bases of that I want to call a Function/Method inside fragment. Android Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a Handler for this and call resetTimeout() when the user does something:

```kotlin
  val timeoutHandler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
    onTimeout()
    true
  }

  fun clearTimeout() = timeoutHandler.removeMessages(0)

  fun resetTimeout() =
      clearTimeout().also {
        timeoutHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, TIMEOUT_IN_MILLIS)
      }


  override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    resetTimeout()
  }

  override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    clearTimeout()
  }

  private fun onTimeout() {
    //we have timed out
  }
```